# How to get DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(“HH:mm:ss.ffffff”) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I would like to get date format like "20/06/2019 13:20:04.8517209" in Javascript

Comment: what is `ffff`?

Comment: @randomSoul It is _seconds fraction_

Comment: @LGSon - You mean `milliseconds`?

Comment: @randomSoul Yes, I meant that

Comment: @LGSon - Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 d = new Date()
 date = d.toLocaleString() + "." +d.getMilliseconds()
 output: "20/06/2019, 13:22:03.517"
```

For cleaner version try to use moment js: https://momentjs.com/

```
moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS')
```